Quill Better table clear issue
I am developing an application using angular and Quill Better table to render table form excel and Word.
When I copied and pasted the table inside the quill I selected the data in the quill using ctrl+a and clicked on delete it deleted the data and the cursor is not present in the quill to enter the data.
Here is the link to reproduce the issue     https://codepen.io/soccerloway/pen/WWJowj
enter code here

